# How Can split String to multiple lines with php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

How Can split String to multiple lines with php

I am trying to print String come from phpMyAdmin and echo it to multiple lines I also use bootstrap frame work .

I use this code .

```
<p><?php echo $course_description; ?>  
                        </p>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoAc9.png)

Comment: Are they inserted in database line by line?

Comment: I assume [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) is what you're looking for.

Comment: are the string is without space in database?

Comment: I don't know the length of string , and string entered from user to database .

Comment: I found the reason thanks .